# Find the number of solutions to $x^2 ≡ 1\bmod(990)$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Find the number of solutions to $x^2 ≡ 1\bmod(990)$.

Hi everyone, is there a clever systematic way to calculate all the answers, or the number of solutions, or must you use brute force and calculate all squares of $Z_{990}$?I cheated and got all solutions with a little help from a friend (Excel) and got $±1$, $±89$, $±109$ and $±199$.
However I know that the primfactorization of $990$ is $2\times3^2\times5\times11$, does it help me to know that $Z_{990} \cong(Z_2 \times Z_9 \times Z_5 \times Z_{11})$ and if so, how?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
x & \equiv  1 & & \pmod{2} \\
x & \equiv \pm 1 & &  \pmod{5} \\
x & \equiv \pm 1 & & \pmod{9} \\
x & \equiv \pm 1 & & \pmod{11} \\
\end{align}
Solve the $8$ possibilities above using the the Chinese remainder theorem.